# message.content.toLowerCase() is not working for me

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this code

```
    if(message.content.startsWith (prefix + " craft")) {
        let editedmessage = message.content.slice(prefix.length + 1);
        let skill = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(9);

        if(!client.msgs[skill]) return message.reply("I cant find that skill"); {
            client.msgs[skill] = [message.author.id]
        }
            if(!client.msgs[skill].includes(message.author.id)) client.msgs[skill].push(message.author.id);
            {

            message.reply("You can now " + editedmessage)
        }
    }
```

It puts the message.author into a JSON file, with the command "!v craft T6 Plate Armor", but I would like  the command to be case insensitive. For example "!v craft t6 plate armor" would still place the user under the "T6 Plate Armor" value in the JSON file.

The JSON file is formatted like this:

```
{
    "T4 Plate Boots": [],
    "T4 Plate Armor": [],
    "T4 Plate Helmet": [],
    "T4 Sword": [],
    "T4 Battleaxe": [],
    "T4 Mace": [],
    "T4 Hammer": [],
    "T4 Crossbow": [],
    "T4 Shield": [],
    "T4 Leather Shoes": [],
    "T4 Leather Jacket": [],
    "T4 Leather Hood": [],
    "T4 Bow": [],
    "T4 Spear": [],
    "T4 Nature Staff": [],
    "T4 Dagger": [],
    "T4 Quarterstaff": [],
    "T4 Torch": [],
    "T4 Demolition Hammer": [],
    "T4 Bag": [],
    "T4 Cape": [],
    "T4 Fisherman": [],
    "T4 Lumberjack": [],
    "T4 Quarrier": [],
    "T4 Miner": [],
    "T4 Skinner": [],
    "T4 Harvester": [],
    "T5 Plate Boots": [],
    "T5 Plate Armor": [],
    "T5 Plate Helmet": [],
    "T5 Sword": [],
    "T5 Battleaxe": [],
    "T5 Mace": [],
    "T5 Hammer": [],
    "T5 Crossbow": [],
    "T5 Shield": [],
    "T5 Leather Shoes": [],
    "T5 Leather Jacket": [],
    "T5 Leather Hood": [],
    "T5 Bow": [
        "95790380057894912"
    ],
    "T5 Spear": [],
    "T5 Nature Staff": [],
    "T5 Dagger": [],
    "T5 Quarterstaff": [],
    "T5 Torch": [],
    "T5 Demolition Hammer": [],
    "T5 Bag": [],
    "T5 Cape": [],
    "T5 Fisherman": [],
    "T5 Lumberjack": [],
    "T5 Quarrier": [],
    "T5 Miner": [],
    "T5 Skinner": [],
    "T5 Harvester": [],
    "T6 Plate Boots": [],
    "T6 Plate Armor": [],
    "T6 Plate Helmet": [],
    "T6 Sword": [],
    "T6 Battleaxe": [],
    "T6 Mace": [],
    "T6 Hammer": [],
    "T6 Crossbow": [],
    "T6 Shield": [],
    "T6 Leather Shoes": [],
    "T6 Leather Jacket": [],
    "T6 Leather Hood": [],
    "T6 Bow": [],
    "T6 Spear": [],
    "T6 Nature Staff": [],
    "T6 Dagger": [],
    "T6 Quarterstaff": [],
    "T6 Torch": [],
    "T6 Demolition Hammer": [],
    "T6 Bag": [],
    "T6 Cape": [],
    "T6 Fisherman": [],
    "T6 Lumberjack": [],
    "T6 Quarrier": [],
    "T6 Miner": [],
    "T6 Skinner": [],
    "T6 Harvester": [],
    "T7 Plate Boots": [],
    "T7 Plate Armor": [],
    "T7 Plate Helmet": [],
    "T7 Sword": [],
    "T7 Battleaxe": [],
    "T7 Mace": [],
    "T7 Hammer": [],
    "T7 Crossbow": [],
    "T7 Shield": [],
    "T7 Leather Shoes": [],
    "T7 Leather Jacket": [],
    "T7 Leather Hood": [],
    "T7 Bow": [
        "95790380057894912"
    ],
    "T7 Spear": [],
    "T7 Nature Staff": [],
    "T7 Dagger": [],
    "T7 Quarterstaff": [],
    "T7 Torch": [],
    "T7 Demolition Hammer": [],
    "T7 Bag": [],
    "T7 Cape": [],
    "T7 Fisherman": [],
    "T7 Lumberjack": [],
    "T7 Quarrier": [],
    "T7 Miner": [],
    "T7 Skinner": [],
    "T7 Harvester": [],
    "T8 Plate Boots": [],
    "T8 Plate Armor": [],
    "T8 Plate Helmet": [],
    "T8 Sword": [],
    "T8 Battleaxe": [],
    "T8 Mace": [],
    "T8 Hammer": [],
    "T8 Crossbow": [],
    "T8 Shield": [],
    "T8 Leather Shoes": [],
    "T8 Leather Jacket": [],
    "T8 Leather Hood": [],
    "T8 Bow": [
        "95790380057894912"
    ],
    "T8 Spear": [],
    "T8 Nature Staff": [],
    "T8 Dagger": [],
    "T8 Quarterstaff": [],
    "T8 Torch": [],
    "T8 Demolition Hammer": [],
    "T8 Bag": [],
    "T8 Cape": [],
    "T8 Fisherman": [],
    "T8 Lumberjack": [],
    "T8 Quarrier": [],
    "T8 Miner": [],
    "T8 Skinner": [],
    "T8 Harvester": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must are converting the `message.content`, aka the `skill` to lowercase, but you are looking for mixed-case keys: `client.msgs[skill]`

Your `client.msgs` key is `"T4 Plate Armor"`, which is not equal to `"t4 plate armor"` (lowercase version), so it will never find it.

#### Solution

Keep a lowercase map to the mixed-case version

```
//create a map of lowercase keys to mixedcase (actual) key names
const lowercaseToMixedcase = {}; //create the map
Object.keys(client.msgs)
  .forEach(key => lowercaseToMixedcase[key.toLowerCase()] = key); //populate it

if(message.content.startsWith (prefix + " craft")) {
    let editedmessage = message.content.slice(prefix.length + 1);
    let lowercaseSkill = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(9); //save the lowercase key. Looks like "t4 plate armor"
    let skill = lowercaseToMixedcase[lowercaseSkill]; //take the lowercase key, and use it to get the actual key name, e.g. "T4 Plate Armor"

    if(!client.msgs[skill]) return message.reply("I cant find that skill"); {
        client.msgs[skill] = [message.author.id]
    }
        if(!client.msgs[skill].includes(message.author.id)) client.msgs[skill].push(message.author.id);
        {

        message.reply("You can now " + editedmessage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: @RasmusHornung I edited the answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: That is so cool! If its not too much to ask, I have a command that also recalls the users in the array. It should be able to do the same when using the command @Codebling

Comment: @RasmusHornung I don't know what you're asking

Comment: Check my own answer @Codebling

Comment: @RasmusHornung I see it, but I still don't understand what you're asking. You want to do be able to use case-insensitive skill there too? You should be able to do that using the same technique.

Comment: I would like that to also be the lowercaseToMixedcase, the command. 

It will only work if I mention the value "!v who T7 Bow" and not "!v who t7 bow"

Comment: The goal here is to provide knowledge for you. If you don't understand how this works, I can provide more explanation, simply let me know which part is not clear. Once you understand the technique, you should be able to reproduce this behaviour wherever you need (it's basically just copy/paste anyhow)

Comment: @RasmusHornung don't forget to upvote and accept helpful questions and answers

Comment: I feel like I have tried to copy/paste the code you gave me in every order possible. But I can't seem to get it working. It is still returning...
I have put what I have right now in the new answer, can you explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @RasmusHornung using other answers to post temporary code is not a great way to do this. Usually it's better to move the discussion to StackOverflow Chat or to post a new question. I'll comment on the other answer

Answer (score 0):

```
´´´
if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + " items")) { 
        let filter = message.content.slice(prefix.length + 8) 
        let item = message.content.slice(7) 
        let _skill = client.msgs[filter]
        /* if(!_skill) return message.reply('I cant find that skill') */
        const whoEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed() 
            .setColor('#0099ff') 
            .setTitle('These are the items that you can choose from') 
            .setAuthor('VINDICTIVE CRAFTER BOT', 'https://i.imgur.com/uz8xDax.jpg') 
            .addField(Object.keys(client.skills),  "Remember to define your skill with a tier") 
            .setFooter('This bot was created by BigTibbies'); 
        message.channel.send(whoEmbed); }

´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + " who")) { 
        /* let filter = message.content.slice(prefix.length + 5)  */
        let item = message.content.slice(7) 
        let _skill = client.msgs[filter]
        let lowercaseSkill = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(7); //save the lowercase key. Looks like "t4 plate armor"
        let _skill = lowercaseToMixedcase[lowercaseSkill]; //take the lowercase key, and use it to get the actual key name, e.g. "T4 Plate Armor"
        if(!_skill) return message.reply('I cant find that skill')
        const whoEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed() 
            .setColor('#0099ff') 
            .setTitle('These players can craft ' + item) 
            .setAuthor('VINDICTIVE CRAFTER BOT', 'https://i.imgur.com/uz8xDax.jpg') 
            .setDescription(`${_skill.map(user => `<@${user}>`).join('\n')}`) 
            .setFooter('This bot was created by BigTibbies'); 
        message.channel.send(whoEmbed); 

    }
```

Comment: Again, using additional answers is not a good way to post temporary code. `_skill` is defined twice. Javascript should give you an error when you try to redefine it. Next, `_skill` is being referenced as if it were an array (`_skill.map()`), but it is not. It is a string. It just contains the key name, like "T4 Plate Armor". You can't map that. It looks like you forgot a step, that of retrieving the data from `client.msgs`. It would be easier to keep all of the data straight with better names, like `skillName` instead of `skill`. Add the removed line `_skill = client.msgs[mixedcaseSkillName]`

Comment: So to summarise what has to happen with this code: 1. get the data you want from the message `rawItemName = message.content` 2. convert it into lowercase `lowercaseItemName = rawItemName.toLowerCase()` 3. get the mixed-case key from the map `itemName = lowercaseItemNamesToMixedcaseItemNames[lowercaseItemName]` 4. get the actual data from the object `item = client.msgs[timeName]` 5. use the data `item.map(user => ...`

Comment: Debugging will help you figure out what's not working with your code. Post new questions if you need more help